# How to change Text in EditTexts in other tabs

Tags: android

Afternoon guys, my problem is:
I have a main tab that contain a 'Search' button, when it's pressed it should load data from the database (which is OK) and apply it to all the tabs (here's the problem)

How an i supposed to do this, is it possible?

If it's not possible, is there any way to pass info trought tabs? Like the customer ID so i could search his info whenever the tab changes?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Ye is possible. Save the content in one global variable and use it in the next tab. In your case if it is string save declare one private/public string variable outside the tabs, when is needed assign data to the string, and use it in the same in the next tabs or whatever you want.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: this is probably the easiest way to go about it. you could also have a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in that tab that will be changed, but it's way more complicated than Nikola's solution.